# icons not showing vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using [element UI](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element) and im using the component daterangepicker

this is my file

```
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI)
```

and my date range picker looks like this[image]

i dont know why the icons is not showing i already import the css file

Comment: Can you try require('element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css') instead of import.

Comment: Probably some path is wrong. Try to see in the browser's Network tab if you get 404 for something

Comment: Which are you using? VueCli or custom build? If custom, then check your url loader config.

Comment: still the same @latovic......

Comment: @Beginner, shouldn't it be " import Element from 'element-ui'; ", " Vue.use(Element); " ?

Comment: @justMe lol thats in the docs so i just follow it

Comment: @codtext i have error 404 https://imgur.com/a/VBFSXBW

Comment: @Beginner, when I looked into the README.md file, I saw sample import of Element, not ElementUI

Comment: @codtext im using laravel btw

Comment: check this out http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart @justMe lol

Comment: @Beginner did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

In your scss file, do this:

```
/* just in case, you like to change theme color */
$--color-primary: blue;

/* icon font path, required */
$--font-path: '~element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/fonts';

@import "~element-ui/packages/theme-chalk/src/index";
```